# How to order a collection property using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, collections

**Periods** is a collection containing properties '**periodStart**' and '**periodEnd**' for each Period.
I need to order the grid by the value of the last 'periodEnd' of each Period.

I thought that the code below would work, ...

```
var result = from sched in schedles
    orderby sched.Periods.Last().periodEnd descending
    select new Grid
    {
     ID = sched.ID,
     Name = sched.Name
    };
```

but instead I get the error -->

> *Message: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '... Last[Period](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[... Period])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

I'm sure this is a simple issue for the more advanced developers, but I know I'm missing some piece of understanding. 
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me understand the limitations of this orderby statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a host of common LINQ methods that are [not supported by LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx). `Last()` is one of them. If instead you use `First()` you will get

> The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation.

So you should do

```
orderby sched.Periods.OrderByDescending(p => p.periodEnd)
             .FirstOrDefault().periodEnd
```

You must order the `Period`s by some property to tell EF what "first" is. You can use `FirstOrDefault()` without guarding against null reference exceptions, because the whole expression is translated into SQL. it's not executed as in-memory LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this will get the result you want:

```
var result = schedles.OrderByDescending(x => x.periodEnd).Select(new Grid
                                                                 {
                                                                      ID = sched.ID,
                                                                      Name = sched.Name
                                                                 });
```